# Reference Request: Group Theory via the Group Action Perspective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, group-actions

I am looking for a higher undergraduate or graduate level textbook that introduces group actions after groups just as many textbooks introduce modules after rings.

I think the semigroup/semigroup action vs. group/group action vs. ring/module ("ring action") symmetry is not currently exploited as much as it could be.  Especially considering they are mild abstractions of a collection of plain vanilla functions acting on a set.

On the same note, a reference to an abstract algebra textbook with a significant chapter on semigroups (and actions) would be appreciated.  A semigroup action is just a few points of data short of a finite automata.  Because of this, and because of formal languages, semigroups show up a lot in computer science, and one can get quite far quite quickly.  There are also deep algebraic results, see for example the Chomsky–Schützenberger enumeration theorem.

Comment: I found Martin Isaac's book is very useful is this direction....

Comment: I think all the books define group actions after defining group :P

Comment: What are you looking for exactly, and what direction. I feel like most books with group theory, or on group theory have group actions (the Sylow theorems for example). Plus are you focused on finite groups. Representation of group is all about groups acting on vector spaces. Geometric group theory is basically about groups acting on metric spaces.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth For an opposite direction, please see Arnold, V.I., ODE text. :)

Comment: I'm looking for group actions appearing early in the exposition of groups, not in anything complicated.  Many books prove many theorems in group theory, such as Sylow's, before group actions are introduced.  The expositional order I'd like to see is:  Functions on a finite set, semigroups and semigroup actions, bijections on a finite set, then groups and group actions.  According to preference, one could interleave matrices acting on coordinate vectors.

Comment: Bhaskar Vashishth:  Acually, in a way, you can.  A group action is just a monoid action, and you can define monoid actions before you even touch the notion of a group.  :)

Comment: @RexButler I have 4 abstract algebra books on hand and an undergraduate group theory book, and all of them have group actions before Sylow. Pretty sure the majority of algebra books introduce group actions, and use Sylow theorems to show off the power of the idea. It sounds like, from reading your post again, and the comment, that you want something like "abstract algebra for theoretical computer sciences" Is that right? Perhaps [this answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10916/uses-of-algebraic-structures-in-theoretical-computer-science/10929#10929) has some things that would...

Comment: interest you. Particularly [this book](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf) which looks interesting, and opens up with semigroups, and has semigroup actions. It looks interesting, but I have not looked at it enough to really comment.